# Make pre-existing strings of single events repeating in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

I imported a calendar from an external site onto Google Calendar for a church website. I need to string together separate events into one repeating event so that they can be edited en masse.

For an example, Event X occurs on Monday every week. When I imported the calendar from a .csv file, it added Event X every Monday as a *separate event* until about June 2017, where it stops.

Is there a way that I could make each of these multiple Event X's into something like "Event X: repeats on Mondays" so that they could be manipulated as a whole, without doing it separately and deleting the extras by hand?

Answer (score -3):

See http://www.gcaltoolkit.com/  Unfortunately, there's no google-native way to delete multiple events.

Comment: Can you expand on this? How will this solve the problem? Is this your app?